# Cannot Navigate after Logged In

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp

I made the application before going to the Store Page then required to login first. So checked first. When it did log in, it can directly navigate to the Store Page. But if not logged in, the user must login and after clicking the login button, it will navigate to the "Store" Page. Likewise if you want to navigate to the "Koleksi" Page

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="store" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Tapped="store_Tapped" Source="images/new icon/BSE-book-icon-store.png"/>
                <Image x:Name="bukukoleksi" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="koleksi_Tapped" Source="images/new icon/bse-icon300-w8-KOLEKSI.png"/>

<callisto:CustomDialog x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="LoginDialog" 
                       Title="Login"
                       Background="#FFFCDAA2" BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <StackPanel x:Name="loginBox">
                <TextBlock x:Name="spacerLogin" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Width="300" Height="50" Text=""/>
                <Grid x:Name="loginEnter">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="FailedMessage" FontSize="17" Text="Login failed!" Foreground="Red" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="email" Text="Email:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="18" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFCA6402"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="emailBox" PlaceholderText="Email" FontSize="17" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="password" Text="Password:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="18" Height="40" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFCA6402"/>
                    <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" PlaceholderText="Password" FontSize="18" Height="40" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button x:Name="loginBtn" Background="#FFCA6402" Content="Login" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Click="loginBtn_Click" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <Button x:Name="cancelLoginBtn" Background="#FFCA6402" Content="Batal" Margin="20,20,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Click="cancelLoginBtn_Click" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ProgressRing x:Name="loadingLogin" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFCA6402" IsActive="False"/>
                </Grid>
```

code:

```
private void store_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((App)(App.Current)).UserName == "Sign in to your account")
            {
                LoginDialog.IsOpen = true;
                loginDetail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                loginEnter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                emailBox.Text = "";
                passwordBox.Password = "";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Store));
            }
        }

        private void koleksi_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((App)(App.Current)).UserName == "Sign in to your account")
            {
                LoginDialog.IsOpen = true;
                loginDetail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                loginEnter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                emailBox.Text = "";
                passwordBox.Password = "";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(koleksibuku.KolesiPage));
            }
        }

private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            loadingLogin.IsActive = true;
            FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ProsesLogin();
        }

        private async void ProsesLogin()
        {
            FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            loadingLogin.IsActive = true;
            try
            {
                var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
                filter.ServerCredential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential("BSE_Win10(1)", "mahonidatastream", "Maho1019");
                var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
                string urlPath = "https://...m/user/auth";
                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", emailBox.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",passwordBox.Password)
                };
                var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(urlPath), new Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //RequestException();
                    loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
                }

                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                bool error = jsonObject["error"].GetBoolean();
                //string message = jsonObject["message"].GetString();
                if (error == false)
                {
                    LoginDialog.IsOpen = false;
                    FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    ((App)(App.Current)).UserName = emailBox.Text;
                    loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    FailedMessage.Text = "Email atau password tidak sesuai/belum terdaftar";
                    loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
                }

            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                //ConnectionException();
                loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
            }
        }
```

I'm having a problem, that when the tap "store" or "bukukoleksi" and after clicking "loginBtn" can not navigate to a page "Store" Page or "Koleksi" Page. Must tap again "store" or "koleksibuku" to be able to navigate to the "Store" and "Koleksi" Page.
How to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm having a problem, that when the tap "store" or "bukukoleksi" and after clicking "loginBtn" can not navigate to a page "Store" Page or "Koleksi" Page

The navigation action is invoked by `Tapped` event, it should not be able to be triggered automatically after click `loginBtn` . A simple way to handle this is to create bool variable to  flag which image is tapped before click `loginbtn`. For example created two variables `isstoreTapped`,`iskoleksiTapped`, once store tapped set `isstoreTapped` to true, same to "koleksi". And after login judge by the two flags to determine which page to navigate.

```
  bool isstoreTapped = false;
  bool iskoleksiTapped = false;
  private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      loadingLogin.IsActive = true;
      FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      ProsesLogin();
      if(isstoreTapped==true)
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Store));
      }
      if(iskoleksiTapped==true)
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(koleksibuku.KolesiPage));
      }

  }

  private void store_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (((App)(App.Current)).UserName == "Sign in to your account")
      {
          LoginDialog.IsOpen = true;
          loginDetail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          loginEnter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          emailBox.Text = "";
          passwordBox.Password = "";
          isstoreTapped = true;
          iskoleksiTapped = false;
      }
      else
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Store));
      }
  }

  private void koleksi_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (((App)(App.Current)).UserName == "Sign in to your account")
      {
          LoginDialog.IsOpen = true;
          loginDetail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          loginEnter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          emailBox.Text = "";
          passwordBox.Password = "";
          iskoleksiTapped = true;
          isstoreTapped = false;
      }
      else
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(koleksibuku.KolesiPage));
      }
  }
```